# problem when sending images through wcf from silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight, image, upload, send

Silverlight uses WCF with **basicHttpBinding**

```
<basicHttpBinding>              
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_BugsService" 
             maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">                  
       <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>              
</basicHttpBinding>
```

I send the image as an `byte[]`, and it's working as long as the image has less than 20KB

but when it's bigger i get the error:

> The remote server returned an error: NotFound

in the Reference.cs

```
public bool EndSave(System.IAsyncResult result) 
{
    object[] _args = new object[0];
    bool _result = ((bool)(base.EndInvoke("Save", _args, result))); // error
    return _result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please catch the exception on the wcf side in the interface implementation and post that.

The error may be related to this problem: 
"[WCF Message Size Issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/bc717eb1-f0a6-4932-868b-8d63b44f598d)"

Answer (score 0):

Check the "maxReceivedMessageSize" property (representing the size in bytes) on the binding configuration. If your data exceeds that size, the message is discarded.